# How to properly read blobs into an oracle sql database in java?

Tags: java, oracle

I am having trouble reading blobs from an oracle database in my java application. Basically, I have a table in my database called `CONNECTIONS`, where I store objects. The objects, and therefore table, have 8 fields, a string, 2 ints and 5 other objects, which I store in the database as blobs. In the first and second column, there are 2 blobs for the start and destination of the connection respectively, where, among other things, a `String name` is stored for the connected stations' names. Among the "gibberish" when trying to read text from the blob on sqldeveloper, I can distinguish these names, and they are all different than one another, hinting as to that my blob reading function is the problem, not the writing one, so here is the part of it that reads blobs:

```
        Statement stm = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM CONNECTIONS";
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
        basics.Connection conn = new basics.Connection();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Blob blob = con.createBlob();
            blob = rs.getBlob(1);
            byte[] bArr = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
            ByteArrayInputStream bs = new ByteArrayInputStream(bArr);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bs);
            Checkpoint tempCh = (Checkpoint) in.readObject();
            conn.setStart(tempCh);

            Blob blob2 = con.createBlob();
            blob2 = rs.getBlob(2);
            byte[] bArr2 = blob2.getBytes(1, (int) blob2.length());
            ByteArrayInputStream bs2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(bArr2);
            ObjectInputStream in2 = new ObjectInputStream(bs2);
            Checkpoint tempCh2 = (Checkpoint) in2.readObject();
            conn.setDest(tempCh2);

            conn.setDuration(rs.getString(3));

            Blob blob3 = con.createBlob();
            blob3 = rs.getBlob(4);
            byte[] bArr3 = blob3.getBytes(1, (int) blob3.length());
            ByteArrayInputStream bs3 = new ByteArrayInputStream(bArr3);
            ObjectInputStream in3 = new ObjectInputStream(bs3);
            Service tempSer = (Service) in3.readObject();
            conn.setService(tempSer);

            Blob blob4 = con.createBlob();
            blob4 = rs.getBlob(5);
            byte[] bArr4 = blob4.getBytes(1, (int) blob4.length());
            ByteArrayInputStream bs4 = new ByteArrayInputStream(bArr4);
            ObjectInputStream in4 = new ObjectInputStream(bs4);
            String[] tempSt = (String[]) in4.readObject();
            conn.setProducts(tempSt);

            conn.setCap1(rs.getInt(6));
            conn.setCap2(rs.getInt(7));

            Blob blob5 = con.createBlob();
            blob5 = rs.getBlob(8);
            byte[] bArr5 = blob5.getBytes(1, (int) blob5.length());
            ByteArrayInputStream bs5 = new ByteArrayInputStream(bArr5);
            ObjectInputStream in5 = new ObjectInputStream(bs5);
            ArrayList<Section> tempSec = (ArrayList<Section>) in5.readObject();
            conn.setSections(tempSec);

            basics.Connection.connections.add(conn);
        }
```

Where basics.Connection.connections is a static list of basics.Connection objects, and con is a java.sql.Connection object passed by my main class (I know, bad class naming). Now, the issue is that this code:

```
    java.sql.Connection con = Database.DBConnect();
    Database.readConnectionsFromDatabase(con);
    for(Connection conn : Connection.connections){
        System.out.println("From: " + conn.getStart().getStation().getName() + " : " + conn.getStart().getStation().getID());
        System.out.println("To: " + conn.getDest().getStation().getName() + " : " + conn.getDest().getStation().getID());
    }
```

prints the exact same thing 2336 times. (The amount of connections in the database). Specifically, it prints this:

```
From: Wetzikon : 8503123
To: Winterthur : 8506000
```

where the connection with Wetzikon as its start and Winterthur as its destination is the last one, the 2336th connection in the database. I've tried changing the method in many ways, having resulted to nothing, other than sometimes the code not working at all and throwing exceptions left and right. I am a total beginner to databases, and have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing the BLOB to the DB correctly, you should be able to read.  But I see that you are casting blob length to int, which is not correct as BLOB is supposed to be a large object.

byte[] bArr = blob.getBytes(1, **(int)** blob.length());

instead I would suggest to use getBinaryStream() to construct your input stream.

```
InputStream bs = lob.getBinaryStream();
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bs);
```